# vue3-style-components render duplicate classes in dom

Tags: javascript, vue.js, styled-components, vuejs3

In my vue3 project, I used vue3-style-components, but when I add class in components which is created by vue3-style-components it renders duplicate classes.
like this:

[image]

How can I prevent duplicate class rendering?

This is my vuejs code:

[image]

And This is Style-components Code:

[image]

Comment: It's just a guess, but you export `Button` twice.

Comment: This happens not only to buttons but also in every styled-components where I have used custom classes

Comment: Have you found any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesnt answer your question - but I would recommend destructing your props/theme not on the individual css attributes but as a wrapping function and then using the `css` function from styled-components as well, like:

```
import Styled, { css } from 'vue3-styled-components'

const props = ['type', 'shape']

const ButtonStyled = Styled('button', props)`
  ${({ type, theme }) => css`
    background: ${ type !== 'default' && theme[`${type}-color] + '' }
  `}
`
```

Because this operation can be expensive, so performing the callback to get the type and theme variables over and over could really slow down performance.

Also I would consider whether or not you need to check the type here or if that maybe is a task better suited for the theme - if there is no `theme["default-color"]` then you can just use the nullish coalescent operator as such `theme[`${type}-color`] ?? ''` to the same effect, if will then default to an empty string if the first variable is null or undefined.

As for your actual issue - its difficult to tell unless you supply some information about where these classes are actually applied, because I cant see any of them being set in the code you supplied.